# How to make the range an variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make the range as an number according to my last row calculation but I can't find a way to do it.

Please refer below for the double asterisk.

```
Sub TestVBA()
    OptimizeVBA True
    Dim startTime As Single, endTime As Single
    startTime = Timer

    Dim testnames As Range, testvalues As Range
    Dim lookupTestNames As Range, lookupTestValues As Range
    Dim vlookupCol As Object

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long

    'Dim LastLine As Long
    'LastLine = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    'Set testnames = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("C8:C399")
    **Set testnames = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("C8:C&lastRow")**
    Set testvalues = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("O8:O399")
    Set lookupTestNames = Worksheets("Graph").Range("A5:A172")
    Set lookupTestValues = Worksheets("Graph").Range("T5:T172")

    'Build Collection
    Set vlookupCol = BuildLookupCollection(testnames, testvalues)

    'Lookup the values
    VLookupValues lookupTestNames, lookupTestValues, vlookupCol
    endTime = Timer
    Debug.Print (endTime - startTime) & " seconds have passed [VBA]"
    OptimizeVBA False
    Set vlookupCol = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `lastRow` inside of double quotes.

**Incorrect**

`Set testnames = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("C8:C&lastRow")`

**Correct**

`Set testnames = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("C8:C" & lastRow)`